# Segmentation Fault ( core dumped ) with the command bash

Tags: bash, solaris, sparc

I'm using SUN Solaris-8 and i tried to install an application to run it into : i failed because i got insuffisant disk space.
So today i delete some useless thing in the disk but when i try to execute the command `bash` this message figure out : 
`Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`.

I read in some forums that's a consequence of a lack of space in the disk or in the memory that's why i got this but i can't fix it .

I also tried the command `adb core` and i got this  :

``` NT_GWINDOWS currently unsupported note segment entry.
core file = core -- program ``bash'' on platform SUNW,Sun-Blade-1500
SIGSEGV: Segmentation Fault
data address not found ```

Any idea about that .?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question. I think you'd be better off on [su].

Comment: I'm not so sure asking what's causing a process to `SEGV` should be moved - determining the cause can be considered an implicit programming question.  What does `pstack core` show?

Comment: @AndrewHenle it shows too much lines like this ` 000560ac parse_and_execute (8c400, 0, a9cf0, 4, ac750, b0010) + 50c
 0005595c ???????? (b5, b0010, 35128, 0, 4, 9)
 00055b04 maybe_execute_file (1, ac750, 1, ae000, ae010, ae010) + 24
 000204b8 ???????? (8c400, 8c400, 1, e, 0, 160)
 0001fa0c main     (8c400, 8c400, 8cc00, 8c400, 0, 0) + 694
 0001f360 _start   (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) + b8`

Comment: Maybe weren't the useless things you removed that useless? What says `type bash`?

Comment: Try running `ldd bash` . Any shared libraries not found?

Comment: HI @jlliagre : that says `bash is /usr/bin/bash`

Comment: hi @MarkPlotnick i got this `ldd: bash: cannot open file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Yes Mark's command was wrong, run `ldd /usr/bin/bash`

Comment: I got this @jlliagre                                                                                `libcurses.so.1 =>        /usr/lib/libcurses.so.1
        libsocket.so.1 =>        /usr/lib/libsocket.so.1
        libnsl.so.1 =>   /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1
        libdl.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/libdl.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /usr/lib/libc.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /usr/lib/libmp.so.2
        /usr/platform/SUNW,Sun-Blade-1500/lib/libc_psr.so.1`

Comment: `pkgchk -v SUNWbash`?

Comment: @jlliagre got this : `/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/bash
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/bash.1`

Comment: Is `export | grep LD_` showing anything?

Comment: No, `export :  command not found`

Comment: `printenv | grep LD_`

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/SUNWspro/lib:/usr/openwin/lib:/opt/sfw/lib:/usr/local/lib`

Comment: `unsetenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH; bash --noprofile --norc -c date`

Comment: the date is not correct in the system :/

Comment: `Sat Jul 15 23:56:17 MEST 2000`

Comment: Yes, but `bash` ran properly!

Comment: but when i launch command `bash` : i got this `Segmentation Fault` . I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with one of the configuration files as bash looks to start properly after disabling them:

```
bash --noprofile --norc
```

Alternatively, the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable might provide incorrect or incompatible libraries, removing it might help too:

```
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Note, if you are using `csh`, use `unsetenv` instead of `unset`.

Comment: Thank you so much ! When i use your first command the bash is activated !  but if i'm not using `csh` what is the command replacing `unsetenv` ?

Comment: Once an environment variable is unset, it stays unset for the current shell and all its children unless of course it is set again. Under `bash` and other bourne shell compatible shells, you unset a variable with the `unset` command.

Comment: so to work in `bash ` mode i have to execute this command `bash --noprofile --norc` ? no only `bash` ?

Comment: If unsetting LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't fix the issue, you need to figure out which one of the configuration files is bogus (/etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile , ~/.bashrc, etc.) and fix it. You'd better ask a new question in the right site ( unix.stackexchange.com ) as stackoverflow is for programming questions and shell scripting is not considered a first class citizen here.